# Cross compiling from MinGW on Fedora 18 to Windows (64 bits) for Ocaml/TclTk program

Tags: windows, mingw, ocaml, cross-compiling, fedora

everything is in the tittle.
I've made some research on the subject and found this  : http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Windows_cross_compiler.

I've followed the steps one by one, reaching the "How to set" part but when I try to compile (as the Mingw README said `make MINGW_HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32`) I obtain this :

```
...
File "topfind.ml", line 171, characters 4-27:
Error: Unbound module Toploop
make[2]: *** [topfind.cmo] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/local/aturbin/mingw32-ocaml/build/findlib/src/findlib'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/aturbin/mingw32-ocaml/build/findlib'
make: *** [stamp-build-findlib] Error 2
```

Any ideas about what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Proper cross-compilation for OCaml currently requires a set of patches which you can find at http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5737 ; the patches are being integrated in the trunk version of ocaml right now, so I guess that bug report should contain the latest information.

Comment: So it seems to be fixed but I don't know how can I have the cross-patches-rev4-2013-07-01-safe3.tar.gz that could allow me to try a cross compilation.
Maybe it's a jenkins project but it requires to be registered on it :s

Comment: I think you still have to apply some patches, and you should be able to register on the bug tracker (no restrictions) so as to download the patches.